# Ignore false login in table

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, jakarta-ee, select

i have a table which contains users login and logout dates. When app crashes and user logins again it can look like this:

```
user | log_in_out | date

john | login      | 12.7.2011.9:15
john | login      | 12.7.2011.9:17
john | login      | 12.7.2011.9:18
john | logout     | 12.7.2011.9:25
john | login      | 12.7.2011.9:45  
john | login      | 12.7.2011.9:55 
john | logout     | 12.7.2011.9:57
```

And i want to select the first login(9:15) and corresponding logout(9:25), then the second login(9:45) and corresponding logout(9:57) etc. I have already done this in java code level. It can be done on sql/hibernate level?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Save the session id too. Invalidate the session when the user logout.

Answer (score 0):

Create such a mapping and create a JPQL query. I think you should add session id to connect logins with logouts.

```
@Entity
class Register {
  String user;
  @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
  LoginType log_in_out;
  Date date;
  //TODO getters and setters
}
enum LoginType {
 login, logout
}
```